# Java merging streams by common value

Tags: java, java-stream

I have method like:

```
private X findMatchingValuesInStream(Stream<DocumentDto> a, Stream<FolderDto> b) {
    // TODO: return Pairs matched by documentDto.url and folderDto.url
}
```

I know that there is only one match by `url` field and i want to return a Pairs that's have the match.

So for example if we had `documentDto` with `url="asasa"` and some other fields set and `folderDto` with `url="asasa"` and some other fields set i want to return for example Pair of this elements.

Finally my method will return a `List` of these elements.

I am not sure how to do it with streams?
I tried something like:

```
    a.filter(c -> b.anyMatch(d -> d.getUrl().equals(c.getUrl())))
```

But i don't know hot to create from it a `Pair` with `c` and `d`.

Comment: you would end up returning such list of pairs or just a single pair? you need to define that `X` in your signature at least.

Comment: `Stream` is not a list in a sense that you can't consume one element of a stream more than once. If you want common elements, you have to drain both streams into two sets (or any other collection for that matter), and then look for their intersection. You will not be able to use any of these streams after you drain them.

Comment: I would return list of Pairs or some Other collection. Other option than streams So? How could i do this in Java?

Comment: You should not look at a stream as if it was a collection. A stream is a _pipeline_, which either has one more element "passing through it" right now, or doesn't. It will always be just "one more", and it's a misconception to think that there can be two, three or five. From description of your task, you make it clear that you think in terms of collections - and so you should use collections.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use stream as your input. Streams are not holders for your data. Rather they are used as a means of processing data.

Another point to consider is that stream is NOT an `Iterable` and you won't be able to iterate over it. The Collection interface is a subtype of `Iterable` and has a `stream` method, so it provides for both iteration and stream access. Therefore, Collection or an appropriate subtype is generally the best return/input type for a public method.

First create a map using folders where key is the url and value is the folderDto. Then for each document look for the map to get the matching folder instance, and then create the Pair. I have used `Map.Entry` as a better alternative to `Pair`. If you prefer `Pair`, you may merely substitute it.

Here's how it looks.

```
private List<Entry<DocumentDto, FolderDto>> findMatchingValuesInStream(Collection<DocumentDto> a, Collection<FolderDto> b) {
    Map<String, FolderDto> folderByUrl = b.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(FolderDto::getUrl, Function.identity()));
    return a.stream()
        .map(d -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(d, folderByUrl.get(d.getUrl())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```